# How to call on Appium desired capabilities for testing

Tags: javascript, appium

I'm very new to Appium, so apologies for some upcoming question that might seem obvious to most.

So I'm using [wd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd) as my client library to test our native app with Appium.

The following code works ok;

```
var wd = require('wd');
const { Webdriver } = require('wd');
var Q = wd.Q;

desiredCaps = {
    'browserstack.user' : 'xxx',
    'browserstack.key' : 'xxx',
    'app' : 'bs://xxx',
    'device' : 'iPhone XS',
    'osVersion': '15',
    'platformName' : 'iOS',
    'name': 'iOSTest',
    'browserstack.debug': true,
    'browserstack.networkLogs': true,
    'browserstack.appium_version': '1.22.0',
    'autoGrantPermissions': true,
    'autoAcceptAlerts': true,
    'autoDissmissAlerts': true,
    'browserstack.appiumLogs': true,
    'browserstack.deviceLogs': true,
    'appium:element-wait': '20'
};

driver = wd.promiseRemote('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub');
driver.init(desiredCaps).then (async function () {
    // Click on CMP Accept and Close element
    await driver.setImplicitWaitTimeout(15000);
    let closeCmp = await driver.element("xpath", '//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="ACCEPT AND CLOSE"]');
    await closeCmp.click();
```

However, what I'd like to do is use the same desired capabilities for multiple tests.

Is there a setup file somewhere in appium that I can add these values to (my website testing framework is nightwatchjs, and this has config files)?

If so, how would I call these desired capabilities for each of my tests? I'm presuming I can't just edit the `driver.init(desiredCaps)` code to be `driver.init(//location of file with desired capabilities)`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AppiumBoot](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot) framework, it use yaml to run Appium auto test. It makes using Appium very simple, and no need to write java or python code.

[demo video](https://www.zhihu.com/zvideo/1542517089130147840)

[demo code](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot/tree/main/example)

In your case, you can write desired capabilities information into `driver.yml`, and include `driver.yml` in other yaml file

1. driver.yml

```yaml
- init_driver:
    executor: http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
    desired_caps:
      platformName: Android
      platformVersion: '9'
      deviceName: f978cc97
      appPackage: io.material.catalog
      appActivity: io.material.catalog.main.MainActivity
      automationName: UiAutomator2
      noReset: true
```

2. include `driver.yml` in other yaml file

```yaml
- include: driver.yml 
- sleep: 2
- swipe_up:
```